# adding elements in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I have an array of 5 elements ex. `arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`; I want to add elements between        these elements, and place them in new array `arr1 = [1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,5,0,0,0];`. When i alert `arr1` i get the same array as it is, but when i alert `arr1.length` i get that it`s length is 5, when it is actually 20. Can you help me fix this, or tell me why do i get that result. Here is an example of the code i am using:

```
function niza(val,times){
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0;i<times;i++) {
    arr.push(val);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

and then this:

```
var y1=0;
var arr= [];
var a = new Array();
for (var j=0;j<Niza1.length;j++) {
  y1 = Niza1[j];
  arr = y1 + "," + niza(0,11);
  a.push(arr);
}
```

where Niza1 holds the 5 elements mentioned before in `arr`, and a holds the elements mentioned in `arr1`.

Comment: You're creating a new Array that will be given 5 strings. I can't reconcile that with your desired result. Is this some sort of homework assignment?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure to understand the code you wrote, but do you know you can add multiple elements at once with `arr.push` ?

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var array2 = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++) {
    array2.push(array1[i], 0, 0, 0);
}

//array2 == [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Nice answer. At least this is clear code. Nicely formatted :)

Comment: +1 - It's not a re-usable like p.s.w.g's answer but it is a simple and clear answer.

Comment: @user3242508 I saw what you tried to say (but you tried to edit my answer instead of adding a comment ...). If you want to add `n` zeroes and not strictly three, I need to know how do you determine how many zeroes you want to add ?

Comment: that is why i use the first function posted before

Answer (score 4):

You question is a little hard to follow, but try something like this:

```
function inject(original, val, times) {
    var res = [];
    for(var i=0; i < original.length; i++){
        res.push(original[i]);

        for(var j = 0; j < times; j++){
            res.push(val);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/78tsx/)

Comment: I have tried this code, but it doesn`t just put n-zeros(which is the variable times) between the main numbers, but it multiplies the main numbers for "times" times. Hope i was clear.

Comment: @user3242508 Then you must have done something wrong when testing it. See the demonstration; the output is `[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that would work with an arbitrary list and length, and is therefore reusable:

```
function inject(original, values) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < original.length ; i++) {
        result.push(original[i]);
        result.push.apply(result, values);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(inject([1,2,3], [0,0,0])); 
// output: [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]

console.log(inject([1,1,1], [2,6,2,6])); 
// output: [1, 2, 6, 2, 6, 1, 2, 6, 2, 6, 1, 2, 6, 2, 6]
```

It leverages the the native `apply` ([here's an explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)) function to execute the `push` with an arbitrary list of arguments, defined by the `values` array.